# sort tuple based on parameter that may exists or not

Tags: python, sorting

I have s list of tuples like this

```
 [(u'Delhi NCR', 148, 'checked'),
  (u'New Delhi', 51),
  (u'Gurgaon', 20),
  (u'Faridabad', 18),
  (u'Ghaziabad', 17),
  (u'Greater Noida', 16),
  (u'Noida', 11, 'checked'),
  (u'Sonepat', 7),
  (u'Palwal', 5),
  (u'Gautam Buddh Nagar', 2),
  (u'Rewari', 1)]
```

I want to move tuples having `checked` parameter in them to the top.Problem is the 3rd parameter `"checked"` may not be present in all the tuples, but only in selected tuples.

If my tuple length is uniform (`"checked"` parameter is present in all the tuples) I can do the sorting like this

```
loc_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[2])
```

Comment: Supposed 'checked' is not there then what would be criteria of sorting two tuples? City name? or code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort by length:

```
>>> L = [(u'Delhi NCR', 148, 'checked'),
...   (u'New Delhi', 51),
...   (u'Gurgaon', 20),
...   (u'Faridabad', 18),
...   (u'Ghaziabad', 17),
...   (u'Greater Noida', 16),
...   (u'Noida', 11, 'checked'),
...   (u'Sonepat', 7),
...   (u'Palwal', 5),
...   (u'Gautam Buddh Nagar', 2),
...   (u'Rewari', 1)]
>>> print sorted(L, key=len, reverse=True)
[(u'Delhi NCR', 148, 'checked'), (u'Noida', 11, 'checked'), (u'New Delhi', 51), (u'Gurgaon', 20), (u'Faridabad', 18), (u'Ghaziabad', 17), (u'Greater Noida', 16), (u'Sonepat', 7), (u'Palwal', 5), (u'Gautam Buddh Nagar', 2), (u'Rewari', 1)]
```

Or:

```
>>> sorted(L, key=lambda x: x[-1] == 'checked', reverse=True)
[(u'Delhi NCR', 148, 'checked'), (u'Noida', 11, 'checked'), (u'New Delhi', 51), (u'Gurgaon', 20), (u'Faridabad', 18), (u'Ghaziabad', 17), (u'Greater Noida', 16), (u'Sonepat', 7), (u'Palwal', 5), (u'Gautam Buddh Nagar', 2), (u'Rewari', 1)]
```

Comment: Haidro I was thinking if OP wants to sort on the basis of first argument if `'checked'` string is not there then `sorted(lofts, key=lambda x: x[-1] if x[-1] == 'checked' else x[0])` should be answer. correct?